# Heroku Sockets Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, socket.io

I have the following example using Node.js for the server that sends data via Socket.io to a Javascript file. All works well locally, but when I uploaded to Heroku, it does not. I have tried a lot of tips I found online, but I am always stuck and can't get it through. At the moment, I don't get errors, but I also can't see the values coming through.

Here is the code I use at the moment:

```
var express = require('express');
var socket = require('socket.io');

//store the express functions to var app
var app = express();
//Create a server on localhost:3000
var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);

//var server = app.listen((process.env.PORT || 3000, function(){
  //console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", this.address().port, app.settings.env);
//});
//host content as static on public
app.use(express.static('public'));

console.log("Node is running on port 3000...");

//assign the server to the socket
var io = socket(server);
//dealing with server events / connection
io.sockets.on('connection', newConnection); //callback

//function that serves the new connection
function newConnection(socket){
    console.log('New connection: ' + socket.id);
    socket.on('incomingDataToServer', emitFunction);

    function emitFunction(data){
        //setInterval(() => socket.broadcast.emit('ServerToClient', new Date().toTimeString()), 1000);
        let randNum;
        setInterval(function(){
            //get a random value, and assign it a new variable
            randNum = getRandomInt(0, 100);
        }, 1000);

        socket.broadcast.emit('ServerToClient', randNum);
        //following line refers to sending data to all
        //io.sockets.emit('mouse', data);
        console.log(randNum);
    }
}
```

And the Javascript here:

```
let socket;
socket = io();
socket.on('ServerToClient', socketEvents);
function socketEvents(data){
  incomingData = data;
  console.log(data);
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Your static files are being served?

Comment: What doesn't work? Check browser developer console.

Comment: What do you mean if my files are served?

Answer (score 0):

Write app.use before the app listen
and modify app.listen as below and check heroku logs for console message.

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
var server = app.listen(port, function() {
        console.log('Server running on ' + port + '.');
});
```

if It still not work let me know.